# Embeding GitHub gist into Docusaurus v2 docs

Tags: reactjs, github, markdown, gist, docusaurus

I'm new to Docusaurus and wonder is there a way to embed GitHub gists into docusaurus docs?

I found this module: https://github.com/winoteam/docusaurus-gist-embed but I don't seem to get it to work.

Comment: What did you try to make the module work?

Comment: Split paragraph with an additional newline

Answer (score 2):

Easy one, install this package in your Docusaurus project

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gist

the in your markdown add the `import` statement along with a Gist JSX code with your Gist id as shown below:

```
---
title: yourtitle
---
import Gist from 'react-gist';

<Gist id="9b9985dbf8163ade22b71f2ccf20cb51" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Docusaurus 2 is based on MDX so any react component you put in the markdown should render, including an iframe with a gist or whatever you want.